# How to use the Mojang API with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, api

The Mojang API allows you to access information related to the Players that play the game. There is a documenation to the API which can be found [here](http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API). However, since I am not so experienced with using an API , I'd like to know how to grab Username History of a Player. On the Documentation, under `UUID -> Name history` there is a URL, `https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/<uuid>/names`. I know how to get the UUID of a player, and by using the above URL in PHP, I get this output;

---

```
[{"name":"JizzInYaTaco22"},{"name":"_scrunch","changedToAt":1423047892000}]
```

---

How do I style this output to make it only show the names of the player? Here's a link showing what I'd like for it to show: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6wNn.jpg)

Here's my code:

$username comes from a form on a separate php page.

```
$username = $_POST["username"];

// Get the userinfo
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' . urlencode($username));

// Decode it
$json = json_decode($content);


// Save the uuid
$uuid = $json->uuid;
var_dump($json, $json->id, $uuid);
// Get the history (using $json->uuid)
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles' . urlencode($uuid) . '/names');

// Decode it
$json = json_decode($content);

$names = array(); // Create a new array

foreach ($json as $name) {
    $names[] = $name->name; // Add each "name" value to our array "names"
}

echo 'UUID: ' . $uuid . '<br />Name history: ' . implode(', ', $names);
```

Comment: This is JSON. You can use `$names = json_decode($json)` to get an object and then use `foreach ($names as $name) { echo $name->name; }`.

Comment: Ah I see! JSON! So, I'm going to update my question with my code that I have, again, since I do not know how to work with API's, could you direct me on how to?

Comment: I wouldn't see this as working with API's, but rather "how to load JSON from an external URL". A simple Google search should do wonders. See it as multiple tasks instead of one big one. You've already successfully loaded the data ("how to load url php"). Now you need to decode it ("how to decode json php") and iterate through it ("how to get json value php"). The code I posted in my first comment includes both of these. Just switch out `json_decode($json)` with `json_decode($uuid)`.

Comment: I appreicate all your help:) But I seem to have a problem with `foreach`. I get this error, `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. I have updated my code in the question.

Comment: Yeah my bad - I didn't realize you never loaded the data. If you check my answer you should be able to figure it out. Let me know if there's anything you need more explanation for.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I noticed that the JSON text contains a UNIX Timestap, how can I access this and display it next to the usernames?

Comment: Check out what the key is called and since it doesn't always appear, only add it to the string if it isn't empty (use the empty function I mentioned)

Comment: The key is called `changedToAt`

Comment: Please post answers as answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is JSON.

You can request the data using [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) (which will, by default, execute a GET request) or [`cURL`](http://www.php.net/curl) for a more advanced way of getting data from an URL.

Decoding can be done using [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) and reading the properties of the object it creates. Also note that I've used [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) in case there's special characters in the username.

```
<?php

$username = $_POST["username"];
$url = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" . urlencode($username);

$content = file_get_contents($url); // Loads data from an URL
// eg. {"id":"360d11df2b1d41a78e1775df49444128","name":"_scrunch"}

$json = json_decode($content);

print_r($json);
/*
 *  stdClass Object
 *  (
 *      [id] => 360d11df2b1d41a78e1775df49444128
 *      [name] => _scrunch
 *  )
 */

var_dump( $json->id ); // string(32) "360d11df2b1d41a78e1775df49444128"
var_dump( $json->name ); // string(8) "_scrunch"
```

Let's get a bit more advanced and business-like for just a second in order to increase readability:

```
class MojangApi {
    const BASE_URL = 'https://api.mojang.com/';

    public static function getInstance() {
        static $instance;

        if ($instance === null) {
            $instance = new MojangApi();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    protected function callApi($url) {
        $fullUrl = self::BASE_URL . $url;

        $rawJson = file_get_contents($url);

        return json_decode($rawJson);
    }

    public function getUserInfo($username) {
        return $this->callApi('users/profiles/minecraft/' . urlencode($username));
    }

    public function getNames($uuid) {
        $result = $this->callApi(sprintf('user/profiles/%s/names', urlencode($uuid)));

        $names = array();

        foreach ($result as $singleResult) {
            $names[] = $singleResult->name;
        }

        return $names;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$api = MojangApi::getInstance();

$userInfo = $api->getUserInfo($_POST['username']);

var_dump($userInfo->name); // eg. string(8) "_scrunch"

// ---------------

$usernames =$api->getNames($uuid);

print_r($usernames); // Array ( 'JizzInYaTaco22', '_scrunch' )
```

You'd be able to extend this class with new methods if you need to contact other parts of their API. Simply call `$this->callApi()` with the URL that comes after `https://api.mojang.com/`.

For your original question, super simplified:

```
<?php

// Load the username from somewhere
$username = '_scrunch';

// Get the userinfo
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/minecraft/' . urlencode($username));

// Decode it
$json = json_decode($content);

// Check for error
if (!empty($json->error)) {
    die('An error happened: ' . $json->errorMessage);
}

// Save the uuid
$uuid = $json->id;

// Get the history (using $json->uuid)
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/' . urlencode($uuid) . '/names');

// Decode it
$json = json_decode($content);

$names = array(); // Create a new array

foreach ($json as $name) {
    $input = $name->name;

    if (!empty($name->changedToAt)) {
        // Convert to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $name->changedToAt);

        $input .= ' (changed at ' . $time . ')';
    }

    $names[] = $input; // Add each "name" value to our array "names"
}

echo 'UUID: ' . $uuid . '<br />Name history: ' . implode(', ', $names);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with all of this! This code seems to output this though `stdClass Object ( [id] => 360d11df2b1d41a78e1775df49444128 [name] => _scrunch ) string(32) "360d11df2b1d41a78e1775df49444128" string(8) "_scrunch"`

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK That'd be the `print_r` and `var_dump` functions - they're simply there to show you the output. You can also check out my more "businessy" solution which can be extended to your hearts content. Consider `print_r` and `var_dump` to be more descriptive versions of `echo`.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks for that! The code still outputs the `string(8)` though. After this, could I simply add the information into a variable?

Comment: That still comes from the `var_dump` - just remove them all if you don't need it. I've also updated the answer to reflect on your original question and show you how you can extend the class. [There's also code examples in the link you posted in your question](https://gist.github.com/ezfe/a71feccd3a837a2592f1) or a [more advanced version that can do more things](https://github.com/ozzyfant/AccountsClientPHP).

Comment: This is all seems like a lot of work for me to understand! Thanks for the help, though! But, what I'd like is to display only the name history of a player without showing the JSON code. Here's a website that does this: http://www.mcnamelookup.com/ simply enter "_scrunch" and you'll get the UUID of that player, and it's name history.

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK See my edit - the bottom is the most simplified version of the code to do what you want.

Comment: Okay so the code you have provided now gives me errors, check my question to see the errors :)

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK That's because a bunch of the stuff is placeholders. `$username` needs to be where you get the username from. I'm also not sure that you want the output exactly like that. You proved from your OP that you *can* do some code yourself, so try. The way to program is to fail over and over again until you get the satisfaction of solving something. I had a bug of a missing slash in one of the URLs that I fixed. I also checked for `uuid` but as you mentioned yourself, the API uses `id`.

Comment: Yes, I have found the problem. It seems to be that the $content using the $json -> uuid is not outputting the correct URL. Instead of outputting ` `https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/<uuid>/names` it outputs `https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/names`. Hence the `Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/names): failed to open stream` error. How would I fix this?

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK It seems that `$uuid = $json->id;` is empty. Check with `var_dump($json)` right before. You want an `stdClass` with an "id" property to verify you're getting the correct info. You might be hitting the API too often (one of the [code examples you posted](https://github.com/ozzyfant/AccountsClientPHP) mentions you can only do this once a minute)

Comment: Yes I do get the "id" property and the stdClass. var_dump outputs this `object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["id"]=> string(32) "360d11df2b1d41a78e1775df49444128" ["name"]=> string(8) "_scrunch" } `

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK Hmm.. if it outputs that it should work fine. Can you, just to verify, use `var_dump($uuid)` right before creating the url? (just noticed, there's also a slash missing - it should be `/profiles//names` - verify that the line is identical to mine.)

Comment: Yes, using `var_dump($uuid)` outputs blank.

Comment: That's super weird. What about `var_dump($json, $json->id, $uuid)`? The last two should be completely identical. Please verify that when you receive good JSON, this is also when you're checking whether the uuid can load. Look into [`if (empty($var)) { die('Could not xxx'); }`](http://www.php.net/empty) if you want some error handling.

Comment: Using that var_dump it outputs undefined property of the stdClass. I'll update my question showing exactly how I get the $username value and my whole php code to make things easier :)

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK `$uuid = $json->uuid;` is still not the same as mine. 37 minutes ago; "*I also checked for uuid but as you mentioned yourself, the API uses id*"

Comment: Woops! Finally, it's working! Can't thank you enough for all the help, I've learned a lot and this should help me with future projects. Thanks again!

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK You're welcome - glad we figured it out in the end, and even better that you learned a lot :)

Comment: Very glad indeed! Have a nice day!:)

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK Sorry for the late response - had to get home from work. :) Check out my edit - it includes adding it to the array.

Comment: It's fine :) Thanks again, you've been great!

Comment: I wish I had a high enough reputation to take this into chat! But since I do not, I have one final problem, if a user were to enter a name that they used to own (So, for example, user `_scrunch` had a previous name called `JizzInYaTaco22`. If the user were to enter `JizzInYaTaco22` into the search field, an error appears. `file_get_contents(https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles//names): failed to open stream` Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: As you can see by the [response](https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/minecraft/JizzInYaTaco22) you'll get an "error" key and an "errorMessage" key. Simply implement the same check we did with "changedToAt" but right after the first JSON decoding. (see my edit)

Comment: Ah okay! Yeah I've managed to get it so that if a user enters their previous username, it'll display the same information that their current username would. Thanks again!